# How can I store and retrieve preferences in Android?

Tags: android

How can I store and retrieve preferences in Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Android: Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/package-summary.html)

[Using preferences in android](http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/19/using-preferences-in-android/)

[Preferences Demo](http://marakana.com/forums/android/android_examples/63.html)