# How to get my settings data from a settings layout to my game building code, Android

Tags: android

Hey,
So I'm newer to Android, but experienced in Java, and I'm having an issue with saving/passing the data from my settings menu to my engine I'm using to create my game board for an application im making. I would like to be able to save this data so the next time the app starts the values of these settings would be saved and present. I was looking around the android documentation but so far have had no luck understanding the "PreferenceFragment" and the way to access view's states. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track for the data.

Android uses preferences to do that kind of saving.

This tutorial helped me greatly when I started:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good place to start.
[How can I store and retrieve preferences in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030916/store-and-retrieve-preferences-in-android)